# Android: How to add Url link to the Marker in onMapReady method?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, android-maps

I have created a map using map API and have set marker using latitude and longitude coordinates. I have no idea how to set a Url link to move to a browser on clicking the marker.

Since I have so many marker each marker should move to a diff url, how it is possible?

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
{
    mMap = googleMap;
     if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
     {
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,"Tap on Zoom button to view the Current Location",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    else {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSION_FINE_LOCATION);
        }
    }

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
            new LatLng(12.9969284, 80.25792380000007)).title("A2B Car Parking").icon(
            BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(BitmapFactory
                    .decodeResource(getResources(),
                            R.drawable.red_icon))).anchor(0.5f, 1f));

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
            new LatLng(13.0327601, 80.27573810000001)).title("Free Parking Place").icon(
            BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(BitmapFactory
                    .decodeResource(getResources(),
                            R.drawable.red_icon))).anchor(0.5f, 1f));

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
            new LatLng(13.0414623,80.24994960000004)).icon(
            BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(BitmapFactory
                    .decodeResource(getResources(),
                            R.drawable.red_icon))).anchor(0.5f, 1f));}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement the marker onClick event inside your activity or in your fragment where you have google map

please check below snipet

```
public class MapActivity extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
        implements OnMarkerClickListener
{
    private Marker myMarker;
    private HashMap<Marker,String> hashmap = new HashMap<>();

    private void setUpMap()
    {
                    .......
        googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);

        myMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .title("My Spot")
                .snippet("This is my spot!")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
        hashmap.put(myMarker,url);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {

        if (marker.equals(myMarker))
        {
            Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse(hashmap.get(myMarker));
            Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
            startActivity(launchBrowser);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for yr help... bt how to set diff url to diff markers?

Comment: As mention in my answer, you have to take  `HashMap<Marker,String>` where you have to add all LINK with respect to the Marker as `hashmap.put(myMarker,url);` , once it completed then whenever you click on Marker you have to get the link from HashMap by using marker as a key. `hashmap.get(myMarker)`

Answer (score 0):

Considering mMap is your Map Object.

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {
                    String url = "http://www.example.com";
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(i);
                    return true;
                }

            });
```

Comment: You can use the Tag property of the marker for that. Set the URL to the tag of the marker and in click listener callback procure the URL from the Tag.